# Modern authentication and unattended

Tags: multifactor-authentication

If Modern Authentication is enabled for SharePoint and MFA is not enabled for the used account, is it still possible to use user/pass credentials in an unattended Powershell script, or is it always necessary to use an App registration when Modern Authentication is enabled ?

Comment: i find out that it is possible

Answer (score 2):

You should always be using CID + Certificate (preferred) or Secret for unattended scripts. Ideally, store the information in an Azure Automation account so you don't need to store them in clear text within your script.

Comment: Thanx for your advice, but I would like to know if it is possible.